# Check which props changed in componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When debugging React code, often I find that `componentWillReceiveProps` fires off unintendedly but I am not able to see which prop change is causing this.

Is there a way to check which prop changed in `nextProps` vs. `this.props` without having something like an `if` check for EVERY prop?

Comment: If you want to look at the diff between two objects you'll have to write that yourself.

Comment: of course, ive written my own checks for something like that.  want to see if others have come up with an elegant way to do so as well.  don't expect react to handle something like this

Answer (score 1):

You could use a JS package, for example (just the first result on google) [deep-diff](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-diff), to compare the old and new prop object.